# R Program : Date as Strings "12-04-2014"

Tags: r

Date as Strings "12-04-2014" should return the day with "12"

```
day <- function(day_vector) { 

day_vector <- as.Date("12-04-2014",format = "%d-%m-%Y")

day <- format(day_vector,"%d")

return(day)

}
```

But the above could not get me the desired answer

Answer (score 2):

We can convert to `Date` class and extract the `day`

```
library(lubridate)
day(dmy("12-04-2014"))
#[1] 12
```

---

Or with `strptime`

```
strptime("12-04-2014", "%d-%m-%Y")$mday
#[1] 12
```

---

In the OP's function, the `as.Date` should take the input argument

```
as.Date(date_vector,format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

instead, it was hard coded with '12-04-2014', whereas the input 'date_vector' is not converted to `Date` class and passed into `format`

```
day <- function(day_vector) { 

  day_vector <- as.Date(day_vector,format = "%d-%m-%Y")

  day <- format(day_vector,"%d")

  day

}

day("12-04-2014")
#[1] "12"
```

Comment: how do i get the code in this format  day <- function(day_vector) { 

day_vector <- as.Date("12-04-2014",format = "%d-%m-%Y")

day <- format(day_vector,"%d")

return(day)

}

Comment: @MamathaPS  Isn't it giving the same format after the function got fixed.  Regarding the first two cases, `sprintf('%02d', day(dmy("12-04-2014")))`